# TypeError: 'MIMEText' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, mime

I have the following code (snippet)

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase

msg = MIMEMultipart()

msg['Subject'] = 'Test message'
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = row['email']
msg.attach = MIMEText(HTML_CONTENT, 'html')
filename = newFileName
attachment = open(newFileName, "rb")
part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)

msg.attach(part)
```

At the last line (178) I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/adieball/Dropbox/Multiverse/Programming/python/repositories/cloudologist/exam.py",
>   line 198, in 
>       main()   File "/Users/adieball/Dropbox/Multiverse/Programming/python/repositories/cloudologist/exam.py",
>   line 178, in main
>       msg.attach(part) TypeError: 'MIMEText' object is not callable

I'm a bit confused, as I call MIMEText already at a line above (msg.attach = MIMEText(HTML_CONTENT, 'html')

any help is highly appreciated

Comment: I'm slightly worried about the filename `exam.py`. If this is an actual, live, in-class exam, asking here would be cheating.

Comment: @Blacksilver nope, I just called it exam.py as the script creates certificates (report lab on pdf) for attendees of an internal exam.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
msg.attach = MIMEText(HTML_CONTENT, 'html')
```

your shadow the `MIMEMultipart.attach()` method with a `MIMEText` instance. So when you get here:

```
msg.attach(part)
```

You are actually trying to call this `MIMEText` instance - which is, indeed, not callable (it's the `MIMEText` **class** which is callable, like all python classes).

You of course want to replace

```
msg.attach = MIMEText(HTML_CONTENT, 'html')
```

with

```
msg.attach(MIMEText(HTML_CONTENT, 'html'))
```